# Eclipse Icons license information

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to find out the licensing information for eclipse icons.

Basically I want to use some of the icons provided here and modify them:

[Common Icons](https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/a/a8/Common_icon_elements.zip)

[Wiki Page Common elements](https://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines#Common_Elements)

Are we allowed to modify the Eclipse Icons? If yes, where can we find licensing information of the same?

Comment: Eclipse stuff is licensed using the Eclipse Public License https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/

Comment: I was looking for EPL licences info in the shared link, but it's not mentioned clearly anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You refer to the old bitmap icons. Most of them were recreated **as SVG** and can be found in a [**separate Git repository here**](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.images.git/tree/org.eclipse.images/eclipse-svg).

They are available under the [Eclipse Public License - v 1.0](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.images.git/tree/org.eclipse.images/eclipse-svg/LICENSE.txt).

Please note that there are stricter [guidelines for Eclipse logos and trademarks](https://www.eclipse.org/artwork/) than for icons.

Answer (score 0):

Well after some googling I found a pdf here:

[Eclipse Icons](https://fdocuments.in/download/eclipse-icons)

For all the icons, there are their names mentioned, which we can search across google or search locally inside of Eclipse plugins (I used FreeCommander tool, which searches file name within archives as well). After getting the right plugin where icon is located, we can read the about.html file of that plugin and fetch the License information.